# Which Excel formula to use for calculating with multple matches?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate sales percentages for everything that has a specific match. Are multiple formulas needed such as IF Statement and Count If?

**Sheet 1**
[image]

**Sheet 2**
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? Do you mean partial text match and sale % >0 to be true? Why is there a difference in Red and Blue apples (who would buy blue apples anyway )

Comment: The color of apples doesn't matter. Yes - a partial text match. Any search term that includes "apple" or "orange" etc should be counted. The result should just be the sales percentage >= 0

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNTIFS() but that means changing the title on sheet one to the day only:

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIFS($G:$G,B$1,$H:$H,"*"&$A2&"*",$I:$I,TRUE)/COUNTIFS($G:$G,B$1,$H:$H,"*"&$A2&"*"),0)
```

[image]